# HTML 5, what should I tell my clients?

Tags: html

More of my clients lately are asking me about HTML 5 and I'm trying to get a sense of what to tell them. How long until all the major browsers have standard support for it? How long until I leave HTML 4 behind and only code new projects in HTML 5? What are you telling your clients?

Comment: Apart from telling them the spec won't be finalized before [2022](http://www.webmonkey.com/2008/09/html_5_won_t_be_ready_until_2022dot_yes__2022dot/)?

Comment: @Oded - not really... It is just IE that stands in way of everybody...

Comment: @Aurel300 - Not IE? Tell me it ain't so!!!

Comment: @Oded - Granted, and thank you for the article. But even the article says that browsers will start supporting it long before that. Which begs the question are you going to start coding for it before that?

Comment: 2022? is that enough time for IE to actually comply? Oh, wait, that assumes they actually **WANT** to comply.

Comment: @Spencer - I will, and some parts of the spec will be implemented by the major browsers long before others...

Comment: @Brad - No. If it comes out in 2022 then IE won't properly support it until 2027.

Comment: @TED, you think? They don't even follow the rules *now*, I don't count on them doing CSS3 correctly and I don't count on them doing HTML5 right. They'll always be the bane of web developer's existence.

Comment: the person who talks to the clients is not a programmer. Tell them lies or whatever to get the contract. A salesman doesn't really care what is selling. Anyway this discussion should not happen between a client and a programmer.

Comment: @Elzo - I can't tell if you're serious or not. I'm a developer and I always at least try to speak directly to my clients.

Comment: @Spencer Ruport. Clients have different motivations and logics in their decisions from a developer. A salesman will tell to a client that he needs HTML5 only to charge more extra hours, you as a developer (strictly professional) you will tell that he doesn't need now HTML5 (for a number of good reasons). Who is right? The salesman has the right and maybe the obligation to lie, a professional in IT it should have the moral spine to do the right thing from a technical point of view. So don't mix speaking with clients with programming, they are too apart.

Comment: @Elzo - I believe that's only true in the short term. If we're talking about the amount of work I want the client to have me do and then pay me for my personal belief is $100 isn't worth $500 six months from now. If I see a way to accomplish what they need while making me do less work I'm going to tell them so six months from now when they need more work they'll still have my number.

Comment: Clients don't know what they need and you know. My point is that you should act upon you IT knowledge not on your sales skills, as these 2 things don't go hand in hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already gotten some good answers, but I'll chime in as well.  I wouldn't give your client a blanket "yes" or "no" on html5.  I'd take a look at [what all has changed](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/25-html5-features-tips-and-techniques-you-must-know/) and then break it down into sections based on [how well it's supported](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_layout_engines_%28HTML5%29).

**The Doctype:**

Nothing is stopping you from switching to the html5 DOCTYPE today.  Even browsers that don't understand html5's new tags (most notably IE 6-8) will recognize `<!DOCTYPE html>` as a valid doctype and [not switch into quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode#Comparison_of_document_types).  After declaring that your document is an html5 document, you're free to use (or not use) html5's new tags to your heart's content.  Personally, I've started using the html5 doctype on websites -- even if I have no immediate plans to use html5's new features -- because there isn't any negative side effect, and as a bonus I don't have to try to remember the correct way to write a doctype and charset everytime I start a new page (which I have to do with html4/xhtml).

**New (Layout) Tags:**

Next, you have to figure out why your client is interested in using html5 in the first place.  My guess is that they're interested because it sounds trendy and cutting edge.  In reality, one of the biggest benefits of many new tags (such as `<section>`, `<nav>`, `<footer>`, `<aside>`, etc) is that they make your code much more readable than it would be if the page was filled with `<div>`s everywhere.  This is a great advantage for the coder (and in the future it might help with accessibility), but right now, this change probably makes very little difference to the client.

**New Features (Video and Audio):**

Alternative, the client might have specific html5 features that they want their site to use.  Two of the most popular are the `<video>` and `<audio>` tags.  The great thing about these is that you can easily fallback to Flash, so you don't have anything to lose (as far as browser support goes) by using them.

**Complex Features:**

Other popular new features are `<canvas>`, geolocation, and local storage (not exactly html5, but related).  For these, the fallbacks (if they exist) require a lot more work on your part.  If your client really wants these features, you'll need to figure out which browsers they (or their customers and site visitors) are using, and what percent of their target audience they're willing to leave behind.

**Conclusion**

That got a little long-winded; long story short, I'd tell your client this:
"I'll gladly start using some html5 features immediately.  Remember, though, that the specification is not finalized, and it will continue to change over the next 10 years.  [Around 50-60%](http://marketshare.hitslink.com/report.aspx?qprid=0) of our clients may be using browsers that don't support some of html5's new features, so we'll need to do thorough analysis before adding certain complex features of html5."

Answer (score 6):

Are they asking about specific HTML5 features or HTML5 in general? At my company we haven't said anything to the clients, but we do set the HTML5 doctype as well as using some HTML5 markup - but only markup that works in non-HTML5 compliant browsers. HTML5 doesn't necessary mean you discard older browsers, it depends on which features you implement. You can still use `audio` and `video` tags, as long as you keep a flash fallback - as an example. HTML5 form tags are poorly implemented even in bleeding edge browsers, so using them are not an option.

I suggest you read [Dive Into HTML5](http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/) to see how you can work with HTML5 today, but still support non-HTML5 browsers.

I'll throw in another link; [Modernizr](http://www.modernizr.com/) is a JavaScript library that come in handy if you want use bleeding edge HTML5 or CSS3 features, it detects support for HTML5 tags and some (all?) CSS3 properties.

Comment: +1. Thanks for this. I definitely had a few misconceptions about HTML 5 that this cleared up.

Answer (score 2):

If the clients are OK with using the browsers that support HTML 5 for their applications, then why not :)

If they don't want to use the browsers (and versions) that doesn't support HTML 5, then they can't have it, thats what I would say.

**Edit:**

OK let me put it this way. If they are asking for a suggestion, then ask them what browsers and versions are they comfortable with, if they fall into the area where HTML 5 is supported, then tell them that they can move to HTML 5, adding that its in a nascent state, but support is growing at a good pace.

Comment: +1. Of course if they're insistent I'm not going to tell them I won't write their site in HTML 5. :) But oftentimes they're asking me for advice and right now I'm inclined to tell them it's too soon but I wanted to get an input (and possibly a time table) from the SO community.

Comment: @Spencer: Edited with rewording my suggestion as per the requirement.

Answer (score 2):

> How long until all the major browsers have standard support for it?

Never. If you look at HTML5 as a whole (which you shouldn't), no broser will ever support *it*. For each browser, there will always be dozens of features defined in HTML5 which the given browser does not implement.

> How long until I leave HTML 4 behind and only code new projects in HTML 5?

The language hasn't changed. It's still HTML. So, you cannot say "I code in HTML 4" or "I code in HTML5". You code in HTML.

HTML5 introduces new features. For each feature, you decide independently if you want to use it in your projects. There is stuff defined in HTML5 that you can use **today**. On the other side, there is stuff defined in HMTL5 that currently isn't implemented in any browser. The point is, it depends on the given feature.

Answer (score 1):

Another key question is: What browser(s) do the majority of your clients use? Since medium to large size companies tend to be very resistant to changing browsers, what they use now is what they're likely to use for the forseeable future.

For clients using mostly Firefox, the answer is that Firefox supports a good deal of HTML5 now (version 3.6), & even more in version 4 (2011). For clients using mostly IE, they'll have to wait until version 9 (2011).